# Changing base of a powerpoint shape after rotating

Tags: powerpoint

Good afternoon,
I would like to change the base of a shape after rotating it.
Is it possible to do so ?

To explain a bit more : after rotating my shape I want this new rotated shape to become the new base (horizontal and vertical) of the shape so the square to modify width and height of the shape isn't rotated anymore but a real square parallel with horizon.

Thank you very much for your help,

Kevin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run into this frequently, and the best solution I have for you will only affect shapes that are made up of a single object, as opposed to groups of objects.

What I do is, once the shape is rotated, I then draw a rectangle that covers the entire original shape. This rectangle will provide the unrotated "base" you are looking for. Send the rectangle behind the rotated shape. Then, with the rectangle selected, Shift- or Ctrl-click the rotated object so that both objects are now selected (the rotated shape --must-- be selected second, after the rectangle).

With both objects now selected, use the 'Format' ribbon, locate the 'Insert Shapes' section and click 'Merge Shapes' > 'Intersect'. The result is now a single object that is formatted like the original rectangle and has its original level "base," but is the shape (including rotation) of your original shape.

I'm typically not formatting an object while I'm dealing with the shape, but if your first shape is already formatted, then you can always use the formatting paintbrush to apply the settings to the rectangle before merging the two shapes. Merged shapes always take on the formatting of the first object selected.

This approach does not work with grouped objects, as the 'Merge Shapes' options are not available for grouped objects. Depending on the number of shapes in the group and your level of determination, you could use the above approach on each shape in the group (or at least the ones affecting the size and orientation of your final group), and then re-group them.

Hopefully the attached image will provide further clarity.
[image: Merge Shapes - Base Rotation]